# Difference between dataloader and dataloader CLIq and dataloader.io?

Tags: data-loader, governorlimits, dataloader.io

Can any one explain difference between normal data loader and data loader CLIq and dataloader.io? and What are the governor limits?

Comment: All three products load data into Salesforce. They have somewhat different interfaces and minor limitations. dataloader.io is a [paid product](https://dataloader.io/pricing) above some threshold for free use. What specifically do you want to know?

Comment: @DavidReed thanks for your reply , i want to know import records limit at a time in Bussiness account/person account and schedule data limit in windows task scheduler....etc

Answer (score 1):

There is not a limit on the number of records you can import via a data loader application *as such*. There are limits that apply to data load activity that will indirectly limit the number of records you're able to load in one pass, with a specific batch size, or over a given 24 hour period.

In particular, you should be aware of the API call limit for your organization, which varies based upon your license total and edition. You can find the full  calculation matrix at [API Request Limits and Allocations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm#!). Note that this is an org-wide, rolling 24 hour limit. It is not Data Loader specific, but shared across all clients connecting to your org via the API.

If you are using a data loader in bulk mode, you should note that there are a number of limits specific to the [Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_bulkapi.htm), including a cap of 10,000 batches per rolling 24 hour period.

Additionally, use of data loaders tends to expose issues with your existing code base. For example, if your code is poorly bulkified and you try to load data with a batch size of 200, you may see SOQL or DML limit errors. You can resolve this in the best case by fixing your code or in the worst by reducing the data loader's batch size, which will make your load take longer.

These limits are not product-specific. They apply to any product loading data into Salesforce via the API, including the standard Salesforce Data Loader and dataloader.io. Note that the latter is a paid product with a 10,000 record limit for its free tier.